# Are SQLite rows ordered persistently?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to order a large SQLite table and write the result into another table. This is because I need to iterate in some order and ordering takes a very long time on that big table.

Can I rely in a (Python) iterator giving my the rows in the same order as I INSERTed them? Is there a way to guarantee that? (I heard comments that due to caching the order might break)

Comment: The Python iterator produces rows *in the order SQLite* produces them.

Comment: Like most databases SQLite provides zero guarantees as to the order of rows in the absence of an `ORDER BY`; If you want an order, you must ask for one.

Comment: [_relational model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) defines tables as _sets_ of tuples, as such the order that data were inserted is immaterial. SQL implements a multi-set, yet does not provide any order guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are approaching this wrong. If it is taking too long to extract data in a certain order from a table in any SQL database, that is a sign that you need to add an index.

Comment: Will an index make iterating by order (ORDER BY) fast? All I need is that one columns comes in with all distinct values grouped.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what an index is for.